# pipe with fork and child creationg

Tags: c, pipe, fork

This is my code for a problem that I am trying to solve.
If anyone one have any idea how to solve this please help.
I am trying to create infinity children with as many pipe as the child's that we will create, but I am losing some children with their pipe and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void main() {
    int n;
    pid_t p;
    int pfd[2];
    int val=0;
    int i;

    printf("Enter the number of child you want:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    pipe(pfd);

    while(1) {
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {

            p=fork();
            if(p>0){
                close(pfd[0]);
                sleep(5);
                val++;
                printf("Message %d: Process %d has process id %d and its child has process id %d \n",val,i,getppid(),getpid());
                write(pfd[0],&val,sizeof(val));
                close(pfd[1]);
                //wait(NULL);
                //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            else {
                close(pfd[1]);
                val++;
                //printf("Message %d: Process %d has process id %d and its child has process id %d \n",val,i,getpid(),getppid());
                //while(read(pfd[0],&val,sizeof(val))>0)
                read(pfd[0],&val,sizeof(val));
                //printf("Message %d: Process %d has process id %d and its child has process id %d \n",val,i,getpid(),getppid());
                write(pfd[0],&val,sizeof(val));
                close(pfd[0]);
                _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Message %d: last child's pid is %d and my father is : %d \n", n,getpid(),getppid());    
}
```

OUTPUT IS:
Enter the number of child you want: 3

> Message 1: Process 1 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041
>
> Message 2: Process 2 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041
>
> Message 3: Process 3 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041
>
> Message 4: Process 1 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041
>
> Message 5: Process 2 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041
>
> Message 6: Process 3 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041
>
> Message 7: Process 1 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041
>
> Message 8: Process 2 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041
>
> Message 9: Process 3 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041
>
> Message 10: Process 1 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041
>
> Message 11: Process 2 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041
>
> Message 12: Process 3 has process id 678 and his child's id is : 15041

So my problem is that the `process id's` are not changing and I can't find why

Comment: Your call to `getppid()` will always return the same pid, the parent of all of the processes. Change this to `getpid()`. 

Instead of using `getpid()` for the child, simply use `p`, which is assigned at the fork (`p = fork()` where `p` is of type `pid_t`).

Answer (score 1):

> So my problem is that the `process id's` are not changing and I can't find why

because

```
printf("Message %d: Process %d has process id %d and its child has process id %d \n",val,i,getppid(),getpid());
```

is executed by the parent, so `getppid` (the pid of the parent of the parent) is
always the same, `getpid` also remains the same. The only thing that changes are `val` and `i'.

You only create a pipe once and then use it for all forks, meanwhile you close
the only created pipe and then fork again, this is not going to end well.

You have to create the pipes before you do the fork. Also you are closing the
reading end of the pipe on the parent process, and the writing to the close
reading end. You have to write on the writing end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t p;
    int pfd[2];
    int i;
    int val = 0;
    int n = 3;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        if(pipe(pfd) < 0)
        {
            perror("pipe");
            continue;
        }

        p = fork();

        if(p < 0)
        {
            perror("fork");
            continue;
        }

        if(p)
        {
            // PARENT PROC
            close(pfd[0]);
            val++;
            printf("Message %d: Parent process has process id %d and its child has process id %d\n", val, getpid(), p);
            write(pfd[1], &val, sizeof val);
            close(pfd[1]);
            int status;
            waitpid(p, &status, 0);

            if(WIFEXITED(status))
                printf("Child %d exit status: %d\n", i, WEXITSTATUS(status));
            else
                printf("Child %d did not exit normally\n", i);
        } else {
            // CHILD PROC

            close(pfd[1]);
            if(read(pfd[0], &val, sizeof val) < 0)
            {
                printf("Child %d: could not read from pipe\n", i);
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            printf("Child %d, message: %d. Child pid: %d, parent pid: %d\n", i, val, getpid(), getppid());

            close(pfd[0]);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
Message 1: Parent process has process id 9829 and its child has process id 9830
Child 1, message: 1. Child pid: 9830, parent pid: 9829
Child 1 exit status: 0
Message 2: Parent process has process id 9829 and its child has process id 9831
Child 2, message: 2. Child pid: 9831, parent pid: 9829
Child 2 exit status: 0
Message 3: Parent process has process id 9829 and its child has process id 9832
Child 3, message: 3. Child pid: 9832, parent pid: 9829
Child 3 exit status: 0
```

One last thing: the correct prototypes for `main` are:

- `int main(void);`
- `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);`
- `int main(int argc, char **argv);`

Your `void main()` is incorrect.

Comment: yes that was very usefull but i need the child to create an other child so the next time i will print the child to be a parent and the child's children to printed as a child id

Comment: and i dont know how to malloc pfd for "n" pipes

Comment: You can do `int (*pfd)[2];`. This declares a pointer to `int[2]` array. Then you can require `n` pipes with `pfd = malloc(n * sizeof *pdf);` and then initialized every pipe in the `for`-loop with `pipe(pdf[i])`. `fd[i][0]` is the reading end, `fd[i][1]` is the writing end. `free(pfd)` frees the memory.

Answer (score 0):

When `p>0`, that means you are in the parent process, not the child, and p is the pid of the child.

this

```
printf("Message %d: Process %d has process id %d and its child has process id %d \n",val,i,getppid(),getpid());
```

should be

```
printf("Message %d: Process %d has process id %d and its child has process id %d \n",val,i,getpid(),p)
```

and if you want the child to display a similar message in the `else` block your first statement works, but just change the word child to parent.